# Laravel 5.7 - emails not being sent via command line

Tags: laravel, email, command, command-line-interface

I'm running a 5.7 laravel project and I can send emails from controllers with no issue.

However, when I'm trying to use the same logic to send emails from a command, launched from the command line, the emails are not sent and I get the following error :

```
In AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 445:

  Expected response code 220 but got an empty response
```

Here is my command code :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Email_confirmation;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Mail\ShopOrderConfirmation;


class sendEmailConfirmations extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'command:sendEmailConfirmations';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {

        $ec_global = Email_confirmation::where("due_date" ,">", Carbon::now('Europe/Paris'))->get();

        if (!$ec_global->isEmpty()) {
            foreach ($ec_global as $ec) {
                if (App::environment('production')) {
                    $subject = $ec->shop_name . " - Order confirmation";
                    Mail::to($ec->contact_email)
                        ->send(new ShopOrderconfirmation($ec->contact_name, $subject, $ec->shop_name, $ec->order_date));
                }
                elseif (App::environment('development','test')) {
                    $subject = $ec->shop_name . " - Order confirmation - TEST";
                    Mail::to("me@whatever.net")
                        ->send(new ShopOrderconfirmation($ec->contact_name, $subject, $ec->shop_name, $ec->order_date));
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            $this->info('Empty.');
        }


    }


}
```

The project is running the 6.0.2 version of the swiftmailer package. I can't find the reason why the behaviour is different here.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the SMTP for sending emails with Swiftmailer

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `env` in your app directory to check if the Environment variables are getting through.

Make sure your `MAIL_DRIVER` property in .env is set to `smtp`.

You could also try `tls` for `MAIL_ENCRYPTION` too.

EDIT:

I just looked into SwiftMailer's AbstractSmtpTransport.php file and around line 445 there's this:

```
if (!$response) {
    $this->throwException(new Swift_TransportException('Expected response code '.implode('/', $wanted).' but got an empty response'));
}
```

What that tells me is that you received no response from the mail server.

So once again I recommend checking the output of `env` from the app directory. If your environment variables are not reflected, try updating them and running:
`php artisan cache:clear`
`php artisan config:clear`

And run `env` once again to check if the updates are reflected.